# Why can't I import my shp file into a postgis database with SRID 102631 using shp2pgsql?

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

I have been trying to figure out the reason shp2pgsql isn't working when I try to import a shapefile with SRID=102631. I've had no problems with other SRIDs.  For all shapefiles in 102631, I get this error: Failed in pgui_exec(): ERROR:  AddGeometryColumn() - invalid SRID

Here is a link to one file, for example, that won't import.

[docks.shp.zip](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d73etq4cymbog74/docks.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SRID:102631 is an Esri well-known ID given to NAD 1983 State Plane Alaska Zone 1 (US survey feet). This definition isn't in the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter Registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org).

You might be able to munge the prj file's WKT into something that PostGIS will support. One way would be to find an existing WKT/definition for the same zone but using meters for the unit of measure. The WKID (SRID) would be 26931. My assumption is that the projection method name and/or the parameter names aren't being understood.

Disclosure: I work for Esri and I'm on the subcommittee that manages the EPSG Registry.

Comment: A really good web resource is epsg.io. For example, see http://epsg.io/102631 which also has http://epsg.io/102631.sql for PostGIS